# How to get multiple pages with .load method

Tags: jquery, ajax, .net-core

I'm building a manage account page in net core. I have a menu and I'm trying to load content from other pages on each piece of the menu the user clicks on into the specified div. How can I use the method with multiple pages?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $( '#show ul li a' ).click(function() {

      //$( '#reveal' ).load( '/account/login .' + $(this).attr('href'));
        $( '#reveal' ).load( '/account/enable2fa .' + $(this).attr('href'));
          return false;
        });  
    }); 

<main id="show">    
   <ul>
     <li class="manage-menu"> <a href="main-login">update password</a></li>
     <li class="manage-menu"> <a href="google-factor">manage 2fa</a></li>
     <li class="manage-menu"> <a href="send">send</a></li>
     <li class="manage-menu"> <a href="test1">test</a></li>
     <li class="manage-menu"> <a href="test2">test</a></li>
     <li class="manage-menu"> <a href="test3">test</a></li>
   </ul>
</main>

<div id="reveal"></div>
```

I commented out a line because when I tried it that way it wasn't working properly. It would only show up half the time or flicker and disappear. Would the load method be too resource heavy for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the network panel in your browser to see if it is making the request correctly.  If you have both load statements triggering at the same time, and they are making it to the server correctly, it could be one is trumping the other.

It also depends on the inner contents of what is in those pages, that could be a factor on load.

Comment: Yeah it looks like when I click on one item it loads all the pages.

Comment: The `load` method is async so it won't stop execution after the first load statement...  You have to setup a promise (does load support promises? not sure) or use $.get or $.ajax so that you can define a callback, and trigger the next ajax call.